# Using df.dropna() returns NoneType Object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a piece of code that looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("/my/path/to/spreadsheet.csv", index_col=0)
file = file.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)
file = file.fillna("", inplace=False)
print(file)
```

**Expected Output:**

```
       Profit ($)  Spendings ($)      Total Profit  EOY Profit ($)
Month                                                                       
Jan           200             80               120            3150
Feb           310             50               260                          
Mar           250             40               210                          
Apr           170             70               100                          
May           650            200               450                          
Jun           180            150                30                          
Jul           530            160               370                          
Aug           610            270               340                          
Sep           470            180               290                          
Oct           680            290               390                          
Nov           570            310               260                          
Dec           600            270               330
```

**Current Output:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/my/path/to/OpenSheet.py", line 5, in 
>       file = file.fillna("", inplace=False)
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fillna'

I understand that this means that when I did `file = file.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)` that it somehow became a `NoneType` object, but why is this?

Also, can anyone tell me how to get the expected output?

Comment: Read the docs about the "inplace" parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the `inplace=True` argument modifies your argument in-place, which means the function returns `None`. Change it to

```py
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv("/my/path/to/spreadsheet.csv", index_col=0)
file.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)
file = file.fillna("", inplace=False)
print(file)
```

Furthermore, it looks like your `EOY Profit` column will cause almost all rows to be dropped:

```py
file.dropna(how="any", inplace=True)

file
  EOY_Profit Month Profit Spendings Total_Profit
0       3150   Jan    200        80          120
```

So I would just avoid the `dropna` line entirely

```py
file = pd.read_csv("/my/path/to/spreadsheet.csv", index_col=0)
file = file.fillna("", inplace=False)
    EOY_Profit Month Profit Spendings Total_Profit
0        3150   Jan    200        80          120
1               Feb    310        50          260
2               Mar    250        40          210
3               Apr    170        70          100
4               May    650       200          450
5               Jun    180       150           30
6               Jul    530       160          370
7               Aug    610       270          340
8               Sep    470       180          290
9               Oct    680       290          390
10              Nov    570       310          260
11              Dec    600       270          330
```